# Schedule a task using java

Tags: java, scheduler

I need to schedule a task  using java in a web application.What is more important is ability to pause and resuming the schedule.I know there is TimerTask and Timer but not sure they have this pause option.I miserably failed using Quartz Scheduler neither I have time to debug that piece of code.Can anyone point to an example where a task can be scheduled,paused and resumed ?

Comment: Is there a spring component in your code? Because spring provides a really good and easy to implement timer task wrapper.

Comment: unfortunately its Struts 1 :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you've had issues with `Qartz` but please give it a second look and look at the [CronTrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorials/crontrigger.html). And as an example on `pausing a task` look at this answer: [Quartz Java resuming a job excecutes it many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933676/quartz-java-resuming-a-job-excecutes-it-many-times/1966724#1966724)

Comment: The problem with Quartz is its not getting paused or resumed.

Comment: Please take a look at the linked answer for pausing a CronTrigger.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a plain Thread which a boolean flag to to pause it?

Personally I would use ScheduledExecutorService with a flag.

Comment: I am sorry I am extremely running out of time.Any examples.I know its too much to be greedy but my situation demands so.Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally the task is your code. So until your code provides facilities to pause, other frameworks can't really help. The simplest way to provide pausing is expose a public method that just calls sleep on your thread. Now the framework may call in your public method to pause(sleep) your thread.

Comment: You cannot call sleep on another thrad.

Comment: exaclty!! thats why i said that you would have to expose a method in your task that will sleep the current thread :)

Comment: Except the current thread would be the one that calls the method, i.e. the framework. The only thing that works is to have a method that sets a flag which the task thread checks periodically. And then it would have to call wait rather than sleep so that it can be woken up as well.

Comment: @Michael, so true, actually that itself was the idea...i think i should take some rest