# Unpausing Quartz trigger causes many job executions

Tags: c#, cron, quartz-scheduler

I have a job that is scheduled to run every 30 seconds with a Quartz Crontrigger. The schedule is thus "0/30 * * ? * MON-FRI". It has no problem running.

However, I want to pause the job for one minute. So I call `scheduler.PauseAll();`, which is supposed to pause all triggers in the scheduler. I then have the thread sleep for one minute and then call `scheduler.ResumeAll();`. So my code looks something like this:

```
scheduler.PauseAll();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);
scheduler.ResumeAll();
```

The trigger pauses for the appropriate time, but when it resumes, the job will run twice. I have the jobs set with the misfire handling `.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing()`, so I don't understand why the job executes twice in this case. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933676/quartz-java-resuming-a-job-excecutes-it-many-times) question, but the OP there paused the job instead of the triggers, so I didn't find it helpful.