# Quartz 2 How to ignore misfire instruction

Tags: java, triggers, quartz-scheduler, jobs, misfire-instruction

I'm using Quartz 2.2.1
when i pause a group of jobs or a group of triggers with pauseJobs(GroupMatcher arg0) method, how can ignore misfire instruction?

This solution [Quartz Java resuming a job excecutes it many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933676/quartz-java-resuming-a-job-excecutes-it-many-times) doesn't work anymore beacuse there isn't a setNextFireTime method.

Comment: Solved using this tutorial: [Ignore misfire instruction using cronbuilder](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/Example5)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use withMisfireHandlingInstructionNextWithExistingCount() method.